# How to fit a distribution to the following bar graph in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, distribution, skew

I have a one dimensional vector of integers which I have fit a histogram to using the following

```
df <- data.frame(Class =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,3,2,4,5,6,4)))

ggplot(df, aes(x=Class))+
  geom_bar(data=subset(df,Class==7), fill="steelblue1", width = 45) +
  geom_bar(data=subset(df,Class==125), fill="steelblue1", width = 45) +
  geom_bar(data=subset(df,Class==62), fill="steelblue1", width = 45) +
  geom_bar(data=subset(df,Class==250), fill="steelblue1", width = 45) +
  geom_bar(data=subset(df,Class==1000), fill="steelblue1", width = 45) +
  geom_bar(data=subset(df,Class==500), fill="steelblue1", width = 45) +
  geom_bar(data=subset(df,Class==31), fill="steelblue1", width = 45)+
  geom_bar(data=subset(df,Class==15), fill="steelblue1", width = 45)+
  geom_bar(data=subset(df,Class==8), fill="steelblue1", width = 45) +
  theme_bw()  +
  #theme(aspect.ratio = 1.2/1)+
  labs(title="PPS, Skewness = 2.192",x="Rate", y = "Frequency") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 5))
```

Here i have made up the data. I would like to fit a distribution around the bars without editing the code already there too much. Each time I add geom_hist() the bars disappear. Is there a way around this? Thank you.

Comment: Does `+ geom_density(aes(y = after_stat(count)))` fit your problem? I don't get any bars using your example.

Comment: Ah it does, but I get individual distributions around each bar. Do you have a way to make it a single distribution with one mean? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So here is a piece of codes that shows 2 ways at the same time: (1) with an empirical kernel density distribution in red and (2) with a theoretical normal distribution in blue. I couldn't really use your example code since it didn't give me any bars, so forgive me for using dummy data that has the same column names.

The important bit here is that any density functions integrate to exactly 1. To get these to the same scale as the count-data, you need to multiply the density by the number of observations (`nrow(df)`) to get data on the count scale (which is already computed with `geom_density()`, we just have to call `after_stat(count)). Next, we also need to multiply the count scale data with the width of the bins.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(Class = rnorm(100, sd = 100))

binwidth <- 45

ggplot(df, aes(x = Class)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = binwidth) +
  geom_density(
    aes(y = after_stat(count * binwidth)),
    colour = "red"
  ) +
  stat_function(
    colour = "blue",
    fun = dnorm, 
    aes(y = after_stat(y * binwidth * nrow(df))),
    args = list(mean = mean(df$Class),
                sd = sd(df$Class))
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Similar, but a bit more direct than in teunbrand's answer... and without the theoretical distribution..

It's a bit redundant to call the same geom_bar call so often - most likely not necessary

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Class =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,3,2,4,5,6,4))

ggplot(df, aes(x=Class))+
  geom_bar(aes(x = Class), fill="steelblue1", width = 0.8) +
  geom_density(aes(y = stat(count)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>